# Load The database schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: 7, installation, database

I am following [Install Drupal with PostgreSQL](http://pgedit.com/install_drupal) to install Drupal 7 with PostgreSQL.

I'm stuck with the steps that says to use a script called database.pgsql which should be found the Drupal files.

I can't find that file. The directory that should contain it has the following content.

> [image: screenshot]

What should I do to install Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two extensions for using PostgreSQL with PHP: the *pgsql* extension and the *pdo_pgsql* externsion. The first is required by Drupal 6, while the latter is required by Drupal 7.

I enabled it in the php.ini file and Drupal can now use the PostgreSQL database during installation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this tutorial is up-to-date. You don't need to load database scheme, you can just choose to use PostgreSQL when running the installer at /path/to/drupal/install.php

Comment: Well, is PostgreSQL installed and running on your machine? Here's my screenshot from my local dev environment: http://i.imgur.com/qNic5Mm.png It clearly shows the PostgreSQL option, I am running PostgreSQL 9.3 locally.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial hasn't been updated and it contains instructions that are for Drupal 4.7.x, since it's Drupal 4.7.x to come with a [database.pgsql](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/4.7.x/database/database.pgsql) file. Drupal 5.x doesn't have that file and [its installation instructions](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/5.x/INSTALL.pgsql.txt) don't include that step; the [installation.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/5.x/INSTALL.pgsql.txt) file also says:

> As of Drupal 5.0 installation has been automated by an install script. It is no longer necessary to manually edit the "settings.php" file, and database tables are created automatically.

In Drupal 5 and successive versions, it's enough to have the required extensions to access the database installed and enabled.